# logical error related to malloc

Tags: c, malloc

Here is a code which I have written. I have got some logical error in it.

```
typedef struct bigint_ {

int signbit;
int*ptr;

} bigint;
void print_bigint(bigint big_num);
bigint shift_by_power_of_10(bigint big_num, int d);

main()
{
bigint a;
bigint b;
a.ptr=malloc(6*sizeof(int));
a.ptr[0] = 1;
a.ptr[1] = 2;
a.ptr[2] = 2;
a.ptr[3] = 2;
a.signbit = 0;
b=shift_by_power_of_10(a,3);
print_bigint(b);

}
bigint shift_by_power_of_10(bigint big_num, int d)
{
int len = (int)(sizeof(big_num.ptr)/sizeof(int));
printf("%d\n",len);
big_num.ptr = realloc(big_num.ptr,d*sizeof(int));
int i;
for (i=len;i<len+d;i++)
{
    big_num.ptr[i] = 0;
}
return(big_num);

}
void print_bigint(bigint big_num)
{
int i;
if (big_num.signbit == 1)
{
    printf("-");
}
int len = (int)(sizeof(big_num.ptr)/sizeof(int));
for (i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if (i!=len-1)
    {
        printf("%d",big_num.ptr[i]);
    }
     else
    {
            printf("%d\n",big_num.ptr[i]);
    }
}   
}
```

In function `shift_by_power_of_10()` while printing `len`, I should have got 4,but I am getting len as 2.

Can you please point out the logical error in it.

Comment: @askmish: That's not working code and thus off-topic there.

Comment: People without accounts on Code Review just love suggesting posting debugging problems there. :(

Comment: Typical misunderstanding of the `sizeof` operator when applied to pointers, probably hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sizeof(big_num.ptr) is equal 4 on x86 (8 on x64), because it is size of pointer. sizeof(int) is equal 4 (VS2010), thats why i will get 4/4 = 1 for (running on x86):

```
int len = (int)(sizeof(big_num.ptr)/sizeof(int));
```

If you run it on x64, then you can get 8/4 = 2